# Dockerized Telnet over SSH Reverse Tunnel

Tags: docker, networking, port, telnet, ssh-tunnel

I know that the title might be confusing so let me explain.

The is my current situation:

Server A - 127.0.0.1

Server B - 1.2.3.4.5

Server B opens a reverse tunnel to Server A. This gives me a random port on Server A to communicate with the Server B. Let's assume the port is 1337.
As I mentioned to access Server B I am sending packets to `127.0.0.1:1337`.

Our client needs a Telnet connection. Since Telnet is insecure but a requirement, we decided to use telnet OVER the ssh reverse tunnel.

Moreover, we created an alpine container with busybox inside of it to eliminate any access to the host. And here is our problem.

The tunnel is created on the host, yet the telnet client is inside a docker container. Those are two separate systems.
I can share my host network with the docker with `-network=host` but it eliminates the encapsulation idea of the docker container.

Also binding the docker to host like that `-p 127.0.0.1:1337:1337` screams that the port is already in use and it can't bind to that (duh ssh is using it)

Mapping ports from host to the container are also not working since the telnet client isn't forwarding the traffic to a specific port so we can't just "sniff" it out.

Does anyone have an idea how to overcome this?
I thought about sharing my host network and trying to configure iptables rules to limit the docker functionality over the network but my iptables skills aren't really great.

Answer (score 0):

The port forward does not work, because that is basically the wrong direction. `-p 127.0.0.1:1337:1337` means "take everything thats coming in on that host-port, and forward it into the container". But you want to connect from the container to that port on the host.

Thats basically three steps:

0. The following steps require atleast Docker v20.04
1. On the host: Bind your tunnel to the `docker0` interface on the host (might require that you figure out the ip of that interface first). In other words, referring to your example, ensure that the local side of the tunnel does not end at `127.0.0.1:1337` but `<ip of host interface docker0>:1337`
2. On the host: Add `--add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway` to your docker run command
3. Inside your container: `telnet` to `host.docker.internal` (magic DNS name) on the port you bound in step 2 (i.e. 1337)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It does seem like it suppose to work but even if I do get a connection, I get no prompt.

`telnet 172.17.0.1 19819
Trying 172.17.0.1...
Connected to 172.17.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.`

connecting to Server B directly doesn't cause this issue. 
Do you know how to deal with that?